# Paypal adaptive payment return empty response

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Any budy faced problem like this on paypal adaptive method.
Following is my XML input to payment method for adaptive payment :

```
<payrequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
<requestenvelope xmlns="">
    <detaillevel>ReturnAll</detaillevel>
    <errorlanguage>en_US</errorlanguage>
</requestenvelope>
<actiontype xmlns="">PAY_PRIMARY</actiontype>
<cancelurl xmlns="">http://todolocally.com/home/search_activity</cancelurl>
    <clientdetails xmlns="">
        <applicationid xmlns="">APP-5RY8dfd2819TX105031K</applicationid>
        <deviceid xmlns="">DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE</deviceid>
        <ipaddress xmlns="">122.173.46.114</ipaddress>
    </clientdetails>
    <currencycode xmlns="">USD</currencycode>
    <feespayer xmlns="">EACHRECEIVER</feespayer>
    <receiverlist xmlns="">
        <receiver xmlns="">
            <amount xmlns="">2.00</amount>
            <email xmlns="">jmfullsail1@gmail.com</email>
            <invoiceid xmlns="">INV-JBQJWWZ1KDQH</invoiceid>
            <paymenttype xmlns="">SERVICE</paymenttype>
            <primary xmlns="">true</primary>
        </receiver>
        <receiver xmlns="">
            <amount xmlns="">1.80</amount>
            <email xmlns="">jackbmahoney@gmail.com</email>
            <invoiceid xmlns="">INV-JBQJWWZ1KDQH</invoiceid>
            <paymenttype xmlns="">SERVICE</paymenttype>
            <primary xmlns="">false</primary>
        </receiver>
    </receiverlist>
    <sender>
        <usecredentials xmlns=""></usecredentials>
    </sender>
    <account xmlns="">
        <phone xmlns=""></phone>
    </account>
        <returnurl xmlns="">http://todolocally.com/paypal/adaptive_payments/pay_return/170/${payKey}</returnurl>
        <trackingid xmlns="">TRK-JBQJWWZ1KDQH</trackingid>
    </payrequest>
```

Paypal response is blank Response is blank.anybody faced problem like this?

[Errors] => Array
        (
        )

```
[Ack] => 
[Build] => 
[CorrelationID] => 
[Timestamp] => 
[PayKey] => 
[PaymentExecStatus] => 
[RedirectURL] => 

[XMLResponse] =>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must be using our [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/)..??  You need to make sure your config file is updated correctly.  For example, your request still has the placeholder value for Device ID from the config file.

As for the particular problem you're having, this is because PayPal only supports TLS 1.2 requests in the sandbox (and will make the same change on the live servers next year).

Please [review this post](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/) and let me know if you have any specific questions after that.

The most important info from the post is...

> If you want to use TLS 1.2 you’ll need to upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.1 as a minimum, and then you’ll be able to set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 6 (TLS 1.2).
>
> If you want TLS 1.2 to be used automatically during SSL requests, you’ll also need to upgrade to PHP 5.5.19+ (this is the ideal solution but many projects are still on older PHP versions).

Comment: please see my question. I am stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947414/paypal-transaction-completed-but-empty-response-from-api-random