# Paypal transaction completed but empty response from api (Random)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal API of php. It was ok since 2 years but now its creating problems for some customers. Some of the orders are fine but for few users, the transaction is completed but API doesn't response (throw empty response).

I don't think it will be because of code issue. I am unable to track the issue. Anyone know, why it's showing the random behavior.

The interesting thing is, for the same customer, doing the second time transaction, it works fine. Totally random behavior. Please need expert suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact PayPal Merchant Technical Support, provide with your PayPal account and API request example which go empty response.
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/